# Quick-selecting files in Windows Windows Explorer with same characters

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

In a Windows Explorer you can type the first few letters of a file name and it would automatically jump to that file. But when I've dozen or hundreds of files starting with the same letters it jumps only to the next occurence of the first character.

```
For example:
20-06-2017_08-31-01.jpg
20-06-2017_08-31-30.jpg
...
21-06-2017_08-20-36.jpg
21-06-2017_08-21-06.jpg
...
22-06-2017_08-23-35.jpg
22-06-2017_08-24-05.jpg
```

If I type '22' I want to jump to the first file 22-06... but it jumps only through the 20-06... files. Is there a trick how to do it?

thanks in advance

Comment: I really don't think Windows can do that. Mac does... but I doubt that one feature would be enough to justify the platform move ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it! For me an admissable solution for my sample is to type the first three characters including the hyphen e.g. '22-'